# Use variable only after periodic thread has processed it

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a thread that runs on a periodic basis. The thread clears and updates a hashmap of data from the database.

Say the thread runs every 24 hours at midnight. At midnight the cache gets cleared and then updated with data from the database. During the update process, how can I access this cache only after the thread has finished processing? Sure, I can ensure that the cache is not empty. However, is there another way to do this?

I know this question is kinda vague. I am looking for resources to be pointed to do my own research and investigation.

Comment: After the update, do you want the cache available until next midnight, or just for a short while? If the former, why not just set it to some publicly-available place (like a field with a getter)? Anyone can read from that place, and as long as the variable isn't null, it's what they should use. There are threading issues of course, but that's a whole thing unto itself.

Comment: In this example that I provided it would be until the next midnight. Based on your example wouldn't I have to store in into a variable and then over-write the variable at some point? Essentially what I want to do is avoid interactions with this variable until after the update has taken place

Comment: If the interactions are just "store the reference, and then use that local reference for whatever you need to do," then why do you care if someone uses it? Put another way: how is it different if someone correctly picks up the previous version at 11:58pm, vs "incorrectly" picking up that same version at 12:01am, while the new cache is being calculated?

Answer (score 0):

Use flag **canGet = true;**
before updating the data from db , make this flag false
now clear the map and load it 
this  is similar to the way you have suggested, except the variable is updated only when  update is  completed,Once the update is completed set the flag to true.

while getting  data from map , check the flag ,if it is available get the value from  map

Note : Make this flag volatile

Answer (score 0):

cacheThread : every 24 hours

mainThread : your thread to check if map is populated or not

There are number of ways. Simplest one would be to establish communication between these two threads using low level communication tools like wait and notify on single object and using a flag variable. Where main thread will wait until flag is false and as soon as flag is set cache thread will notify main thread.

Other sophisticated ways include using CyclicBarrier/Phaser. With CycliBarrier you can provide one barrier object to both threads and initial parties would be 2, so when both threads call await method then main thread will proceed and main thread will also reset the barrier so that it can be used on next day.

```
mainThread{
    //some code

      barrier.await();

    //barrier.reset
    //required processing on map

}
cacheThread{
    //Fill map
      barrier.await();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Say the thread runs every 24 hours at midnight. At midnight the cache gets cleared and then updated with data from the database. During the update process, how can I access this cache only after the thread has finished processing?

This is a very common pattern with a number of answers.  I tend to never clear the cache but instead I replace the cache with a new one.

```
 private volatile Map<?, ?> cacheMap = new HashMap<>();
 ...
 private void updateCache() {
    Map<?, ?> newCacheMap = new HashMap<>();
    // ... fill out the newCacheMap somehow
    // once it is filled out then you can replace the one in use
    this.cacheMap = newCacheMap;
 }
```

It is important to note the `volatile` field to make sure that the threads see a fully published cache when they run.

If the cache is too large in memory to have 2 copies (the old and the new) then I would suggest that you switch to using a `ConcurrentHashMap` and add timeout times to each of the elements.  Then you can update the cache map on the fly.  The background thread would add new elements to it and remove old elements on the fly.  Or it could run through the entries in the cache and refresh them live by re-putting them to the map.